# What is the meaning of the percent sign + pipe operator in Ruby, as in "%|"?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I'm trying to understand the script presented on [this site](http://metaskills.net/2010/07/09/interactive-javascript-console-with-textmate/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require ENV['TM_SUPPORT_PATH'] + '/lib/escape.rb'

def terminal_script_filepath
  %|tell application "Terminal"
      activate
      do script "jsc -i #{e_as(e_sh(ENV['TM_FILEPATH']))}"
    end tell|
end

open("|osascript", "w") { |io| io << terminal_script_filepath }
```

Most importantly, the part where the function `terminal_script_filepath` begins with:

```
%| …
… |
```

… and where it is "parsed" in:

```
{ |io| io << terminal_script_filepath }
```

**Which concepts of Ruby are used here?**

I know that `open()` with a pipe helps me feed input to the STDIN of a process, but how does the input get from `terminal_script_filepath` to `io`? I also know the [basic `%` operations with strings](http://old.blog.jimhoskins.com/?p=8), like `%w`, but what does the pipe do here?

Comment: +1 for googleable 'percent' 'pipe'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a string. In ruby, you can define strings in may ways. Single or double quotes are the most common, %s is another. You can also define strings with any delimiter, as used in this script. For example `%^Is also a string^`, or `%$Also a string$`. You just have to make sure to not use those characters inside the string.

The `<<` in this case is being used as a concatenation operation, appending the string to a file, or in this case, a pipe that listens to AppleScript.

Comment: Be careful after **Ruby 2.0** where modifiers can change the interpolation, e.g. `%I[ ]` _Interpolated Array of symbols, separated by whitespace (after Ruby 2.0)_

Answer (score 4):

This is another example of string literal:

```
var = %|foobar|
var.class # => String
```

You can use any single non-alpha-numeric character as the delimiter, like so:

```
var = %^foobar^
var.class # => String
```

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals or 'The Ruby programming language' book by Flanagan and Matsumoto

Comment: @WarHog And the link directly to the section: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation  (I'd edit your comment if I could ;)

Comment: Also, be careful after Ruby 2.0 where modifiers can change the interpolation, e.g. `%I[ ] Interpolated Array of symbols, separated by whitespace (after Ruby 2.0)`